# How to define a global reference to array type and also specify its address in C++

Tags: c++

```
typedef uint8_t        ARRAY_U8[4];
uint8_t                memory[1024];
uint32_t & test_dword = *(uint32_t *) (&memory[256]);
ARRAY_U8 & test_array = *(ARRAY_U8 *) (&memory[512]);

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

The code defines two global variables and specifies their address relative to `memory`, the address of `test_dword` is `memory+256` and the address of `test_array` is `memory+512`

Now, I want to specify the base address of `memory`, in Windows, use VirtualAlloc() to allocate Virtual memory in address 0x20000000, the code is as following:

```
class MEMORY
{
    public：
        MEMORY();
        ~MEMORY();
        uint8_t *memory;
};

MEMORY::MEMORY()
{
    VirtualAlloc((LPVOID)0x20000000, 0x400, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
    this->memory = (uint8_t *)VirtualAlloc((LPVOID)0x20000000, 0x400, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
}
```

Then in main.cpp:

```
MEMORY MEMORY_0;
typedef uint8_t        ARRAY_U8[4];
uint32_t &  test_dword = *(uint32_t *) (&MEMORY_0.memory[256]);
ARRAY_U8 & test_array = *(ARRAY_U8 *) (&MEMORY_0.memory[512]);

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

build and run, the address of `test_dword` is just as expected: 0x20000100, but the address of `test_array` is initialized as `&(MEMORY_0.memory)+512`.

I guess that `test_dword` is zero initialized, and `test_array` is const initialized when program startup. as in .asm file, test_dword is in _BSS SEGMENT, meanwhile test_array is in _DATA SEGMENT.
Are there some descriptions in C++ standard about the differences between the two types? Does there exist some compile options in Visual Studio to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think both break strict aliasing rule, placement new may solve that.

Comment: If you want to do that within the scope of the C++ language then placement new is probably the way to go. Otherwise you would need to configure the linker to do what you want, but we don't know which linker you're using (maybe it would depend on the platform you're building for too).

Comment: The first few lines of main look like you want to interpret the same memory in different "views". Did you considerI using a union for doing that? A union of three arrays, i.e.  uint32_t[256], ARRAY_u8[256] and uint8_t[1024]. You can use sizeof to verify that you did not get misalignments or paddings.

Comment: But new can not specify the base address, for some reason, I have to specify the accurate virtual address of each variable; I know that GNU C support using __attribute__to define these variables in an user-defined section, and specify the base address of the new section in the linker script, but I am using Visual Studio 2010, which does not support config the base address of user-defined sections

Comment: *"But new can not specify the base address"* Look at [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new).

Comment: Yes， placement new can specify the base address of an array，but the returned type is a pointer type， what I need is an array type